# Transform a NoneType into a Surface

Tags: python, pygame

I have problems with my Python code. First when I use the function `pygame.get_image` the screenshot from my webcam is a `NoneType` but I need it to be a surface or at least an image so I can convert it. This is my code :

```
    import pygame 
    import pygame.camera
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()
    pygame.camera.init()
    cam=pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480),"RGB")
    cam.start()

    while 1:
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
        im=cam.get_image()
        screen.blit(im,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update
```

And the Error message is :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
    TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

Comment: No amount of magic is going to transform `None` into a `Surface`. You need to work out why `get_image()` returns `None`.

Comment: I know but that my question in fact, I don't understand why I don't get an image. I did a code with nearly the same things but without the camera set and all worked .  
( I'm sorry I started python a few weeks ago )

Comment: You don't need your `pygame.display.set_mode` bit in the `while` loop either. Move it before that section.

Answer (score 2):

In `pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480),"RGB")` `0` doesn't look like a device, try calling [pygame.camera.list_cameras()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html#pygame.camera.list_cameras) to get a list of devices.

Keep in mind that this module only works in Linux with V4L2 cameras.

Comment: I'm on windows so that's probably why it doesn't work, is there something I can work with on windows ?